# RGDSlam+Mapping+Localization

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Can i do mapping and Localization using rgbdslam using Kinect alone.
thanx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55171/rgdslam+mapping+localization/) by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on 2013-02-13**:
using fuerte on ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can run RGBD-SLAM with a Kinect only, RGBDSLAM does not require a source of odometry such as IMUs and wheel encoders. You can hold the Kinect and move it around. RGBDSLAM constructs a 3D map or your environment while also obtaining the optimized pose (localization).

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on 2013-02-14**:
Our team search alot about methods to do mapping like hector_slam , but we faced alot of problems
map has apppered empty. Any way we will use RGBD-SLAM .Can U help me to do this ??
i will use this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam to do mapping , is it enough ?
@K_Yousif

**Comment by [howyda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3699/howyda/) on 2013-02-14**:
but, idon't know how to make localization using RGBD-SLAM ? Can U help me